# Compiling multiple source files with cffi

Tags: python, python-cffi

I have recently discovered the `cffi` Python module and I would like to use it to write unit tests for some C code I have written in Python. One (arguably simple) thing that I can't wrap my head around is how to compile several C source files into one Python module that can then be imported by Python code.

Say for example I have four C files, `a.c`, `a.h`, `b.c` and `b.h` such that `a.c` includes both `a.h` and `b.h` and calls functions implemented in `b.c`. And `b.c` only includes `b.h`.

If I wanted to write unit tests for functions implemented in `b.c`  I could simply do this:

```
import cffi

with open('b.h', 'r') as f:
    b_h = f.read()

with open('b.c', 'r') as f:
    b_c = f.read()

ffi = cffi.FFI()

ffi.cdef(b_h)
ffi.set_source('_b', b_c)

# import _b ...
```

But what if I want to write unit tests for functions defined in `a.c`?

Comment: What’s [`set_source`](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/release-0.8/search.html?q=set_source&check_keywords=yes&area=default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core idea is to use:

```
ffi.set_source("_mytest", '''
    #include "a.h"
''', sources=["a.c", "b.c"])
```

to compile a module containing both `a.c` and `b.c` and including `a.h`, which itself includes `b.h`.  This uses the [distutils argument](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html) `sources=[..]` to give additional source files to be compiled into the same extension module.  Above that line, you can use `ffi.cdef()` on the C declarations that are of interest to you---usually a subset of both `a.h` and `b.h`.  (You can call `ffi.cdef()` more than once, or just once on a string made by concatenating several pieces.)